# Getting count of filtered rows from all the tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysqladministrator

I am trying to write a stored procedure in MySQL to get count of filtered rows from all tables (in one of our databases, all the tables have same fields). This is what I have written so far but it is taking the row count from the Information Schema and I think row filter cannot be applied on the tables.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `COUNT_ALL_RECORDS_BY_TABLE`()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE TNAME CHAR(255);

DECLARE table_names CURSOR for 
    SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pfh';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN table_names;   

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TCOUNTS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TCOUNTS 
  (
    TABLE_NAME CHAR(255),
    RECORD_COUNT INT
  ) ENGINE = MEMORY; 


WHILE done = 0 DO

  FETCH NEXT FROM table_names INTO TNAME;

   IF done = 0 THEN
    SET @SQL_TXT = CONCAT("INSERT INTO TCOUNTS(SELECT '" , TNAME  , "' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT FROM ", TNAME, ")");
    #SET @SQL_TXT = CONCAT("INSERT INTO TCOUNTS(SELECT '" , TNAME  , "' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT FROM ", TNAME, " "'WHERE char_length(name) < 8'")");

    PREPARE stmt_name FROM @SQL_TXT;
    EXECUTE stmt_name;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;  
  END IF;

END WHILE;

CLOSE table_names;

SELECT * FROM TCOUNTS;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

How can I get the count from the actual user tables where I can apply filters as required. Something like

```
SET @SQL_TXT = CONCAT("INSERT INTO TCOUNTS(SELECT '" , TNAME  , "' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT FROM ", TNAME, " "'WHERE char_length(name) < 8'")");
```